# Issue with working with mirrored space when rigging

Tags: python, math, matrix

I know this is technically a coding space. This is a coding problem, but relative to Autodesk Maya and rigging. This is more theorizing than an actual code example.

I'm trying to create a Python script for FK and IK matching. Right now I'm trying to match FK controls to IK target joints in FK space. My issue is that the rig I'm working with has mirrored limbs. So the right side is mirrored along the Z axis. This allows for a singular value such as 42 inputted into the rotation, to get mirrored similar behavior on both sides. (so 42 on Y will make left and right limbs move outwards)

The right-hand control is mirrored through a parent offset matrix attribute, that defines its space. The issue is that when I run my matching script (that works on the left side) it gives me opposite rotations on the right side (so -16 rather than 16 on a specific rotate value).

I was wondering if this might be to do with getting my values in world space. Should I, instead, be getting the parent space of my objects? As getting it in world space would get transformed relative to the world which would be negative. So, in doing so that's why my behavior does not mirror.

If I were to calculate everything relative to the space that sets the mirror, would this ensure my calculations are all non-mirrored, therefore, technically mirrored?

My code is simple and as follows:

Get FK control (that we want to be matched in world space)
Get FK joint in world space
Get IK joint (our target match) in world space.

Calculate constraint matrix by joint matrix * inverse parent matrix

Calculate rotations offset by inverse constraint matrix * target IK joint matrix.

Decompose to rotations.

cmds.xform(FK_Ctrl, rotations=offset, ws=1)

Thanks.